# Добавление элемента в массив с циклом

Tags: java, android

Есть такая конструкция

```
String[] massiv = { getResources().getString(R.info),"4432"};
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(massiv.length);
HashMap<String, Object> map;
for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("key", massiv[i]);
    data.add(map);
}
```

Всё работает, но, не понимаю как можно добавить элемент в `massiv` программно, теоретически, с других классов, чтобы по нему проходил цикл. Ну например кликаешь по кнопке, событие подхватывает какую то строку, и забрасывает ее в `massiv` и по ней идет цикл. С помощью add можно обратиться только к ArrayList, но с другой стороны там условие `massiv.length`. Надеюсь, вы поняли, что я имею ввиду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте вместо массива список `List`. Его гораздо проще изменять динамически.

```
List<String> massiv = new ArrayList<>();
massiv.add(getResources().getString(R.info));
massiv.add("4432");
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>(massiv.size());
HashMap<String, Object> map;
for(int i = 0; i < massiv.size(); i++) {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key", massiv.get(i));
    data.add(map);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Размер массива в Java задается при его создании и далее изменить его нельзя.

В этой строке:

```
String[] massiv = { getResources().getString(R.info),"4432"};
```

Вы создаете массив и инициализируете его. В итоге у Вас получается массив с **двумя** элементами. Третий элемент добавить в этот же массив нельзя.

Можно, например, заменить какой-либо элемент массива на некий другой, но добавить элемент в **тот же самый** массив нельзя.

Однако можно создать новый массив бОльшего размера, поместить в него элементы старого массива и новый элемент, однако, если Вам нужна такая функциональность, то лучше использовать соответствующие готовые решения, такие как расширяемый массив (`ArrayList`), либо, например, связный список (`LinkedList`).